# How to Protect the sheet name not the entire sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to protect the sheet name by preventing

- any change to the sheet name, or
- the sheet being deleted.

This must be done **without** protecting the entire sheet using the `Protect Sheet` or `Protect Workbook` options.

Is there any way to do this with VBA?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't because every Worksheet or Workbook event I have tried aren't triggered in these cases

Comment: Maybe explain what you are trying to do and someone may offer help. Each Sheet in a Workbook has a unique CodeName, can you reference a sheet in that way? As far as preventing a sheet deletion, there is not much to prevent it, but you might prevent saving the workbook that way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Right click the sheet tab that you wish to protect
2. View Code
3. Copy and paste in the code below

This code disables the delete control on the sheet (but not right click on cell) menu when the sheet is activated. The control is enabled when the sheet is de-activated

The code will also name the sheet "NameOfSheet" when the sheet is de-activated. This is a workaround to prevent the sheet being renamed

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Application.CommandBars.FindControl(ID:=847).Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
Application.CommandBars.FindControl(ID:=847).Enabled = True
Me.Name = "NameOfSheet"
End Sub
```

[image: protect sheet1]

Comment: Just come across this now, this has helped me a great deal, i just wanted to fix the name to "Costing" and the `me.name =` part has helped.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. What you can do, you can make a worksheet a very hidden one (accessible only from VBA) and in case of the deleted sheet, you can copy it and make a copy visible.

Answer (score 0):

Would this approach work?

1. Select all cells in the sheet, then UN-lock all cells with "Lock
   Cells" (yellow background of padlock turns white).
2. Write the name of the sheet in a (fixed or named) cell, then lock
   this cell ONLY ("Lock Cells", padlock background turns yellow).
3. Then Protect workbook, but allow every action, except the first one
   "Select Locked Cells".

   The user can do everything except selecting the cell with the sheetname (and delete rows/columns).
4. Now write a VBA to compare the actual sheetname with the data in the protected named cell (or fixed reference e.g. A1).
5. Run this script either on every change (probably too much) or at least on close of
   the workbook.
6. As long as the sheetname is always in the same cell (e.g. A1), you can then loop through all sheets, compare their name    with the data in cell A1 and correct the sheet name if required.

Comment: Thanks all. My query is how to avoid the rename of a sheet. disabling the delete option on right click.